# Converting ISO date to double during deserialization JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to convert ISO date-time strings in JSON automatically to double value (say epoch seconds) during the de-serialization process using JSON.NET.

Let's say I have a class like below.

```
 public class Announcement
    {

            public string Id { get; set; }

            public string Name {get; set;}

            public double CreatedDateTime {get;set;}
    }
```

I want the ISO datetime (createdDateTime) in the following JSON to automatically convert to CreatedDateTimeMS.

```
{"id": 123, "name": "new announcement", "createdDateTime": "2014-01-05T13:15:30Z"}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way, Write a custom JsonConverter....

Comment: Added more details and an example to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll fight less with the JSON serializer if you have a separate property for presenting the converted value and decorating it with a ScriptIgnore attribute to keep it out of the JSON data.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public double EpochSeconds
    {
        get { return (MyDate - _epoch).TotalSeconds; }
        set { MyDate = _epoch.AddSeconds(value); }
    }
}
```

With this you can use either MyDate or EpochSeconds to get and set the value but it will always be serialized as a datetime in the JSON.  If you want it to be serialized as seconds then just move the attribute.

Comment: Json.Net does not honor the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute.  Instead, you you will need to use `[JsonIgnore]`.

Comment: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - MyDate` ??

Comment: `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - MyDate` will return a TimeSpan.  To keep things simple and avoid newing up a DateTime struct for each call it might make sense to declare something like `private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);` and reference it inside the getter and setter.

Comment: But I guess you mean `MyDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)` :)